# Filter for list not working

Tags: javascript, html, filter, html-select

I want to make a filter for a list which only displays the elements of the list that match the value given in the `<select>` ("0" or "1").

```js
function filterElements() {
 var select = document.getElementById("select");
 var filter = select.value;
 var list = document.getElementById("listElements");
 var elements = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
 var valueElement;
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  valueElement = elements[i].value;
  console.log("filter : "+filter+" ; value : "+valueElement+" ; equal : "+(valueElement===filter));
  if (valueElement === filter)
            elements[i].style.display = "";
  else elements[i].style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="filterElements()">
 <option value="1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="0">Value 0</option>
</select>

<ul id="listElements">
 <li value="1">Element 1</li>
 <li value="0">Element 2</li>
 <li value="1">Element 3</li>
 <li value="0">Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

When I compare the value of the filter and the value of the element of the list, even when they are both "0" or both "1", it always print "false" in the console.
Where did I make a mistake?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: LIs do not have value attributes. Use data-value and `valueElement = elements[i].getAttribute("data-value");` Also use `==` instead of `=== ` if you want conversion between string and numbers

Comment: @mplungjan [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp](They have a value attribute) but indeed it is a number and not a string.

Comment: Please see [**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) and beware w3schools who are to be taken with a grain of salt as they often known to be passing around out of date or plain wrong information. See [**http://www.w3fools.com/**](http://www.w3fools.com/) for more details.

Comment: @Nope luckily they have improved a lot. A fact the w3fools also mentions. I would still prefer MDN though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrongly assumed LIs do not have a value attribute but they do AND it is an integer, but it is used to (re-)number an ordered list and not as a data attribute.

> [**value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)
>   This integer attribute indicates the current ordinal value of the list item as defined by the `<ol>` element. The only allowed value for this attribute is a number, even if the list is displayed with Roman numerals or letters. List items that follow this one continue numbering from the value set. The value attribute has no meaning for unordered lists (`<ul>`) or for menus (`<menu>`).

Using a data-attribute the world of HTML is all right again:

Here they are BOTH strings - alternatively use `==` instead of `===` to get the type conversion for free but in an understandable way:

```js
function filterElements() {
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  var filter = select.value;
  var list = document.getElementById("listElements");
  var elements = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var valueElement;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    valueElement = elements[i].getAttribute("data-value");
    elements[i].style.display = valueElement === filter ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="filterElements()">
 <option value="1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="0">Value 0</option>
</select>

<ul id="listElements">
  <li data-value="1">Element 1</li>
  <li data-value="0">Element 2</li>
  <li data-value="1">Element 3</li>
  <li data-value="0">Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Using querySelector and initialising to selected value:

```js
function filterElements() {
  var filter = document.getElementById("select").value;
  document.querySelectorAll("#listElements li").forEach(function(li) {
    li.style.display = li.getAttribute("data-value")===filter?"":"none";
  })
}
filterElements();
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="filterElements()">
 <option value="1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="0">Value 0</option>
</select>

<ul id="listElements">
  <li data-value="1">Element 1</li>
  <li data-value="0">Element 2</li>
  <li data-value="1">Element 3</li>
  <li data-value="0">Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `typeof filter` is `string` and `typeof valueElement` is `Number`. So `===` gives false.

```js
function filterElements() {
 var select = document.getElementById("select");
 var filter = select.value;
 var list = document.getElementById("listElements");
 var elements = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
 var valueElement;
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  valueElement = elements[i].value;
  console.log("filter : "+typeof filter+" ; value : "+typeof valueElement+" ; equal : "+(valueElement==filter));
  if (valueElement == filter)
            elements[i].style.display = "";
  else elements[i].style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="filterElements()">
 <option value="1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="0">Value 0</option>
</select>

<ul id="listElements">
 <li value="1">Element 1</li>
 <li value="0">Element 2</li>
 <li value="1">Element 3</li>
 <li value="0">Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Reason for li value to be number is

> The value attribute sets the value of a list item. The following list items will increment from that number.
>
> The value must be a number and can only be used in ordered lists

For more info see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp)

Comment: I thought everything is HTML was strings when retrieved by the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

```
function filterElements() {
 var select = document.getElementById("select");
 var filter = select.value;
 var list = document.getElementById("listElements");
 var elements = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
 var valueElement;
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    valueElement = elements[i].value;
    console.log("filter : "+filter+" ; value : "+valueElement+" ; equal : "+(valueElement==filter));
    if (valueElement == filter)
        elements[i].style.display = "";
    else elements[i].style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

=== will check for the type also. So you have to use == , or you can type cast the value and then use ===